# How to reach a docker container from a device that is in the same network as the docker host?

Tags: networking, docker

I have a docker container running in my linux host in the default docker bridge network. The container can reach the internet. (`wget -qO- google.com` works) `ifconfig` shows the ip 172.17.0.2.
My laptop is connected to the same network as my server. It can ping my server, my server can ping my laptop and my docker container can ping my laptop, but my laptop can't ping my docker container. (My server can ping my container too.)
With the use of wireshark I found out that the docker containers ping is coming from the ip of my server.

I read that docker containers connect to the internet using masquerade when connected via the bridge adapter. (I don't know where)
The I read about [masquerade](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Linux_Networking/IP_Masquerade):

*"There is a small caveat and that is that the masquerade function nearly always works only in one direction, that is the masqueraded hosts can make calls out, but they cannot accept or receive network connections from remote hosts."*

I am not sure whether this is true for docker.

Can I somehow initiate a connection to my docker container (in my current configuration) from my laptop?
Why or why not?

What would be needed to do so? (I know about -publish)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way to do this would be to setup a macvlan interface. A macvlan interface emulates the LAN of the host machine, and it gives the container its own IP. You can read about it here: https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-macvlan/

Another way would be to expose the ports on the host machine using the publish option you know about. If the container is running a web server for example, you can expose port 80. Learn about that here: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/
You will then be able to reach the docker by going to the host machines IP and the port you select.

Overall, the macvlan method is harder but is a lot less messy if you run multiple containers, as they each get their own IP. The second method, however is a lot easier and can be setup in a couple seconds.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Docker containers connect to a bridge network running inside the host (think about your local network being like the WAN/internet and the network Docker creates like a LAN and the Docker host like a router)

You can expose ports using `docker run -p` which creates a NAT rule from the hosts IP address to the containers IP address (like if you setup port forwarding on your router to get to a device inside your private network from the internet)

You can also setup routing on the host so the Docker bridge network is directly accessible. To do this, you'd need to make sure the host has IP forwarding enabled, you need to make sure the Docker host firewall will allow incoming connections to the container's IP address, and you need to configure routing on your network (through your default gateway) to route the Docker bridge network IP addresses to the IP address of the host

Besides those options, you can look at other ways to configure Docker networking if the official documentation https://docs.docker.com/network/#scope-of-this-topic

In addition to these methods, you can also SSH into the host and create an SSH tunnel to the container. For instance, if the Docker host is 10.0.0.2 and the container has an IP address of 172.17.0.1 and you'd like you to access nginx on port 8080, you can do `ssh -L 8080:172.17.0.1:8080 10.0.0.2` which will redirect port 8080 on the machine initiating the SSH connection to 8080 on the container